# Java, How to handle both JOptionPane NumberFormatException input string and NumberFormatException:Null error?

Tags: java

In my  program , I have to calculate GPA from given letter-grade and numeric grade.
In the first dialog-box however if I click cancel it gives me numberFormatException null error and if I type string it gives me NumberFormatException input string error.
I have to use try-catch in my program and I have already tried it.Is there anyway I can handle both exception with try-catch method.I also want user to type 1 and 2 for the  letter grade and numeric grade option  receptively and
nothing else.

The following is the code for the program:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class CalcGPA{

    public static void main (String [] args){

        String questionOfOptions = "What type of grade do you wish to enter?\n";
        String letterGradeOption = "Press 1- for letter (A,C,etc)\n";
        String numericGradeOption= "Press 2-for numeric(89,68,etc)";

        String message= questionOfOptions
                       +letterGradeOption
                       +numericGradeOption;

        String endingMessage = "The corresponding GPA is";
        String calculatedGPA="0" ;
        String randomString="kc;lc[ ams[xas";

        String userResponseString="0";
        int userResponseNumerical=0;
        char characterValue='0';

        do {
            userResponseString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
                (null,
                 message,
                 "GPA Calculator",
                 JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            try {
                userResponseNumerical= Integer.parseInt(userResponseString);

            } catch(NumberFormatException.forInputString ex) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            userContinuationOption= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog 
                    (null,
                     "Do You Want to Continue? ",
                     "GPA Calculator",
                     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 

            if(userContinuationOption==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                System.exit(JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
            }

            switch(userResponseNumerical){

                case 1:   
                    String userGradeResponse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
                                                   (null,
                                                   "Enter a Grade.",
                                                   "GPA Calculator",
                                                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    if (userGradeResponse.equals("A")) {
                        calculatedGPA ="4.";                        
                    } else  if (userGradeResponse.equals("B")) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 3.";
                    } else  if (userGradeResponse.equals("C")) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 2.";
                    } else if (userGradeResponse.equals("D")) {    
                        calculatedGPA=" 1.";
                    } else if(userGradeResponse.equals("F")) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 0.";
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog 
                            (null,
                             "Improper input ",
                             "Error",
                             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        break;
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog 
                        (null,
                         endingMessage+" "+calculatedGPA,
                         "GPA Calculator",
                         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;

                case 2:                    
                    String userNumericString= JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
                                                 (null,
                                                 "Enter a Numeric Grade.",
                                                 "GPA Calculator",
                                                 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    int userNumericGradeResponse=0;
                    Integer.parseInt(userNumericString);

                    if(userNumericGradeResponse>=80) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 4.";
                    } else  if (userNumericGradeResponse>70) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 3.";
                    } else  if (userNumericGradeResponse>60) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 2.";
                    } else if (userNumericGradeResponse>50) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 1.";
                    } else if(userNumericGradeResponse>=0 &&
                             userNumericGradeResponse<50) {
                        calculatedGPA=" 0.";
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog 
                        (null,
                         "Improper input",
                         "Error",
                         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
            }

            int userContinuationOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog 
                                            (null,
                                             "Do You Want to Continue? ",
                                             "GPA Calculator",
                                             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 

            if(userContinuationOption==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                System.exit(JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);}
            }

            while(true);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the same thing in another catch block? Although a system exit seems a bit harsh. Receptively? That's a mighty big method!

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but with try/catch blocks you can catch as many exceptions as you like and handle them differently so:

```
try {
    do.something();
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    handleexception(e);
}catch(IOException e){
    handleexception(e);
}catch(Exception e){
    blow.up();
}
```

And so forth and so forth. You should be able to catch each exception type in a different block. but you could also just catch `NumberFormatException` and then check what kind from there. Hope this helps

Comment: I have only learned single try and catch(just one catch block) , if i want to stop the null error when a user cancels JOptionPane as well give message when they input string , what can I do ? They are both same type of exceptions.

Comment: You need to change your thinking, you shouldn't be using a try catch to deal with the null but rather dealing with it:   

    `if(userResponseNumerical!=null){
        letsTry.dosomething();
    }else{//must be null
        System.exit(0);
    }`
Try approaching the problem with this in mind.  (sorry can't get the code to display properly)